# Python BeautifulSoup filtering <IMG ALT> text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup, I need to filter the line result
I would like to get only the text outside "product_available"
Help?

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get("https://www.kabum.com.br/produto/129973/placa-de-video-asus-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1650-4gb-").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

#get model name
for strong_tag in soup.find_all(id="titulo_det"):
    print(strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling)

#get disponibility
for disponibility in soup.find('div',{'class':'disponibilidade'}):
    print (disponibility)



OUTPUT.

#here is the model is formated

Placa de Vídeo Asus NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, 4GB, GDDR6 - TUF-GTX1650-O4GD6-P-GAMING 
   #here is the part of disponibility        
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:bottom">
   #here i need this part only
    <img alt="produto_disponivel" height="32"        src="https://static.kabum.com.br/conteudo/temas/001/imagens/descricao/bot_disponibilidade_on.gif"             width="164"/>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:bottom">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

#all of this part i dont need

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the for loop. Try this:

```
disponibility = soup.find('div',{'class':'disponibilidade'})
print(disponibility.table.tr.td.img)
```

If there are multiple divs which have class="disponibilidade" you can use this code:

```
for disponibility in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'disponibilidade'}):
    print(disponibility.table.tr.td.img)
```

Comment: Thank you i will try, thank you very much for the help

Comment: or just `soup.select_one('.disponibilidade img')['src']`